# How to copy an .exe or any type of file which is hiiden using BATCH FILE?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
{-----------------------------------
rem thx to RBI
rem note nsona.exe is a hidden file
title trigger
copy nsona.exe %temp%
---------end of the script --------}
```

my problem is

`nsona.exe` is not starting since nsona.exe is a hidden file! 
How to fix this?

and also try to answer [how to close a particular window using BATCH or CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255149/how-to-close-a-particular-window-using-batch-or-cmd) too

Comment: I can run hidden executables without any problems on my Win XP.

Comment: oh!! but it doesn't work in win 7 !!

Comment: Can you temporarily unhide it, run it, rehide it? ATTRIB -H file && START FILE && ATTRIB +H file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
xcopy /h nsona.exe %temp%
```

Comment: That's a different question @user3393326. You should post another question for this.