# how to close a particular window using BATCH or CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How do I close a particular window using a batch script?

Example: I have many existing windows open, and I open "My Computer" in Windows 7. How can I close this using a batch script?

also try to answer [How to copy an .exe or any type of file which is hiiden using BATCH FILE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254645/how-to-start-an-exe-or-any-type-of-file-which-is-hiiden-using-batch-file) too!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using SendKeys. Save the following as `Closer.vbs`:

```
set shell = createobject("wscript.shell")
rcSuccess = shell.AppActivate("title of window to activate")
if rcSuccess = 1 then shell.sendkeys "%{F4}"
```

Then make a batch file called `CloseApp.BAT` containing

```
REM Close some App
cscript /nologo closer.vbs
```

And run using:

```
CloseApp
```

Comment: try to make it using batch !!